# I have the attempt to index nil with 'LocalPlayer', how can i fix it?

Tags: scripting, roblox

I'm currently creating a roblox simulator but i can't get over this issues as i'm a very unexprerienced programmer. I hope someone more experienced can help thanks!

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Player = Player.LocalPlayer

local CurrencyGUI = script.Parent
local CurrencyHolderFrame = CurrencyGUI:FindFirstChild("CurrencyHolder")
local stupidityFrame = CurrencyHolderFrame:FindFirstChild("Stupidity")
local coinsFrame = CurrencyHolderFrame:FindFirstChild("Coins")

repeat wait(1) until player.leaderstats
```

error:attempt to index nil with 'LocalPlayer'
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function setupPlayerData(player: player)
    local leaderstats = instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local food = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    food.Name = "Food"
    food.Value = 0
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 0
end
```

Player.PlayerAdded:Connect(setupPlayerData)

stupidityFrame.amount.text = player.leaderstats.stupidity.value
coinsFrame.amount.text = player.leaderstats.coins.value

error:attempt to index nil with 'PlayerAdded'

Comment: You made a spelling mistake:
local Player = Player.LocalPlayer should be
local Player = Players.LocalPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, change `local Player = Player.LocalPlayer` to `local Player = Players.LocalPlayer --Add an s behind "Player"`